# Searching based on field content - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, link-to

So I am creating a ruby on rails application and in my view I have a list of link_to with each being a different console

In my database table I have a field called console.

What I want to do is when a user clicks on a link e.g. Playstation 3, it will return back all records that have Playstation 3 listed in that table column.

I was wondering how I would go about doing this, I have tried searching on the internet but have not found anything similar.

It is for a project that I don't have long to complete. I was owndering what I would state in the link to's in the view and what I would put in the games_controller.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If someone solved your issue you should click the green check mark next to their answer. That will mark their answer as "accepted". Leave the question's title as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic gist is to have a controller action which will return the list of games filtering by console. For example,

```
# GamesController.rb
def index
   @games = Game.find_by_console(params[:console])
end
```

Then you can create a link for any particular console as such:

`link_to 'XBOX', games_path(:console => 'XBOX')`

This should result in a `GET` request to the URL `/games?console=XBOX`

If you've got a pre-defined set of consoles, you might look into making them into constants inside a `Consoles` module to avoid having to hardcode them everywhere.

UPDATE:

Since you are trying to implement both searching and filtering in the same chain, you need to make sure that `find_by_console` isn't called if it's not present.

```
# GamesController.rb
def index
   @games = Game.search(params[:search])
   @games = @games.find_by_console(params[:console]) unless params[:console].blank?
end
```

Comment: Thanks carlos. I now have the following in my GamesController:


@games = Game.paginate(:per_page => 4, :page => params[:page]).search(params[:search]).find_by_console(params[:console])


But I now get the following error:
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

---
What must I do to fix this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sounds like your search method returned no results and then you tried to call find_by_console on it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the ```find_by_console``` method will return ```nil``` if there are no results found. You can resolve this by wrapping the entire expression in an ```Array.wrap``` call, e.g., ```Array.wrap(Game.paginate ...)```

Comment: Hey Carlos, I tried that and whilst it got rid of any error messages it no just displays a blank table and even if you click on a console link or type a product in the search it just returns and empty table. my code is as followed for the index line: @games = Array.wrap(Game.search(params[:search]).find_by_console(params[:console]))

Comment: Since you are implementing both search and filtering in the same chain, you want to make sure that if a filter is not specified, then ```find_by_console``` is not called otherwise it will filter out all results. I've updated the answer above

Comment: Hey Carlos, I done as you said and changed it to the updated index section but I get the following error: NoMethodError in GamesController#index

undefined method `find_by_console' for #<Array:0x7b029a0>. I do not understand why it is doing this as I have what you have in the update and in my index.html.erb I have <%= link_to 'XBOX', games_path(:console => 'Xbox 360')%>.

Comment: If your ```search``` method does not return an ```ActiveRecord relation```, then you can't call ```find_by_console``` on it. Not sure how that method is implemented (manually, a gem, etc.) but it should return a relation in order to support chaining methods properly.